# What is the different between php5 and php5-dev

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

When I install php on ubuntu, somebody use

> sudo apt-get install php5

somebody use

> sudo apt-get install php5-dev

What is the different between them?

Comment: Thank you for your help to format the question. This is 1st time I use stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[php5-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/php5) contains files to develop PHP modules:

> This package provides the files from the PHP5 source needed for
>   compiling additional modules.

[php5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/php5) is a meta package that installs the PHP runtime.

Answer (score 11):

The command

```
  apt-cache search php
```

would tell you the difference:

```
   php5 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
   php5-dev - Files for PHP5 module development
```