# php-config is not installed error in ubuntu 16.04 xampp

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-16.04, phalcon

I am getting php-config is not install error when running the below command to install phalcon.

```
sudo ./install --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

Environment.

ubuntu 16.04

XAMPP for Linux 5.6.15

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just install `php-dev` package:

`apt-get install php-dev`

If you use php5 then it needs to be:

`apt-get install php5-dev`

Comment: please explain what is php5-dev

Comment: "php5-dev contains files to develop PHP modules" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890286/what-is-the-different-between-php5-and-php5-dev